# Upload file from WinForms to .Net Core 3.1 API

Tags: c#, .net

This code has been working for 6 months on .Net Core 2.2, but no longer works when we "upgraded" to .Net Core 3.1.  The file is received on the server, but the other parameters are always null.

Client Code:

```
    public async Task<bool> UploadFile(string sourcePath, string destinationPath, bool createPath, bool overwriteFile)
    {
        bool status = false;

        try
        {
            MultipartFormDataContent multipart = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            multipart.Add(new StringContent(destinationPath), "destinationPath");
            multipart.Add(new StringContent(createPath.ToString()), "createPath");
            multipart.Add(new StringContent(overwriteFile.ToString()), "overwriteFile");
            multipart.Add(new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(sourcePath)), "files", "files");

            // Select the API to call
            string path = $"UploadFile/{multipart}";

            // Make request and get response
            HttpResponseMessage response = await restClient.PostAsync(path, multipart);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string jsonResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                if (jsonResult.Contains("true"))
                    status = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            appLog.WriteError(ex.Message);
        }
```

API Code:

```
    [HttpPost("UploadFile/{multipart}", Name = "UploadFile")]
    [RequestSizeLimit(40000000)] // Max body size (upload file size)
    public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> UploadFile(List<IFormFile> files, string destinationPath, bool createPath, bool overwriteFile)

    {
        // server side code here
    }
```

No obvious errors on the console.  All the other APIs work fine, just this one that utilizes MultipartFormDataContent code no longer works properly.

Comment: .NET Core sacrifices backward compatiblity with API changes should you decide to upgrade to newer versions.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/2.2-3.1

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure multiple parameters like that is not allowed any longer. Luckily it's usually pretty smart about figuring out the object.

Instead of passing multiple parameters, replace the parameters with an object with properties that match the existing parameters. It should work without changes to the client.

```
public class PostBodyMessage
{
 public List<IFormFile> files {get; set;}
 public string destinationPath {get; set;}
 public bool createPath {get; set;}
 public bool overwriteFile {get; set;}
}

[HttpPost("UploadFile/{multipart}", Name = "UploadFile")]
[RequestSizeLimit(40000000)] // Max body size (upload file size)
public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> UploadFile(PostBodyMessage message)

{
    // server side code here
}
```

This should work.

Comment: 1.  How do you assign a file to an IFormFile
2.  How do you add a complex type via:

 multipart.Add(message);

Comment: From the client? If this was working, you shouldn't have to change it...

Comment: Perhaps I'm going about this all wrong.  MultiPartFormData was designed to gather web form data and post it to an API.  That's not exactly what I'm doing.  I have a service that grabs an existing file, sets the parameters, and posts to the API.  Maybe there is another way to accomplish the same thing?  I could base64 encode the file and pass the whole lot as a json object, but I'm not thrilled with the idea of base64 encoding large zip files just to get around this challenge.

Comment: Austin, I don't understand your point.  The old code doesn't work anymore after upgrading to .Net Core 3.1 from 2.2.  I should also point out that the client is a .Net Framework 4.7.2 application, communicating to a .Net Core 3.1 web API

Comment: In the original code I assigned the contents of the file to the IFormFile as follows: 
 File.ReadAllBytes(sourcePath);  Doing that now shows an error "Cannot implicitly convert type byte[] to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile.  So, what is the correct way of assigning the file to the IFormFile?

Comment: Actually, I'd go the other way. You have in the client ReadAllBytes, which would get a byte[] array. So change in the controller classList< IFormFile> to byte[].

Comment: Austin, thank you for your guidance.  I'm now struggling with how to actually send the class object as the one permitted parameter.  specifically, this line:

multipart.Add();